# Android LoaderManager ContentProvider and loading data over network

Tags: android, rest, networking, android-contentprovider

I've searched StackOverflow and googled but I can't find an answer.

I'm trying to build a REST-Service using Virgil Dobjanschis Designpattern B ( http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)

I have an activity with a SimpleCursorAdapter and a LoaderManager to query a ContentProvider. This works for data in my database. Data is re-queried and UI is getting refreshed.

After every query on the ContentProvider a Thread is started to sync the requested data from network, it loads json-objects, parses and save new data to database - everything fine, but the UI is not updated.

I think I have to send my Activity a message to refresh data, but I don't know how and can't find an example how to do that.

So, what is the right way to manage this?

---- Updated ----

I think I didn't explain my problem clearly.
As you can see in this pic:

[image]

Step 7 is working. A Helper-class is updating data.
Step 7' does not happen. I thought this would be a automatic feature of a ContentProvider.

My Helper-class (Resthandler) is updating the database directly without using ContentProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this. I overloaded insert() in my ContentProvider. So I can give ContentValues to it and CP is writing data to db. CP sends notifications to Views.
It is tested and working. I have found this in a book "Programming Android".

Answer (score 0):

You have a SimpleCursorAdapter, which I suppose you use to bind data from the content provider to your UI, correct? If that's true, then you need to move the retrieved Cursor to the cursor adapter every time you update the cursor.

Do this in CursorLoader.onLoadFinished(), by calling either

SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor() or SimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursor().

See the Android training class
[Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html) for a complete example.

Comment: Thanks but this is not a solution for my problem. As I mentioned, refresh of Loader and UI works if data is already in my database. Refresh don't work for data synced new to my database.

Comment: I've found a solution for this. I overloaded insert() in my ContentProvider. So I can give ContentValues to it and CP is writing data to db. CP sends notifications to Views.